# Error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/invariant'

Tags: meteor, reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, meteoric

Not sure if any one of you have ever faced this issue. I have tried checking various sources online but nothing solved my issue.

I am following a tutorial on how to create a Meteor+ionic+react application from this link

https://medium.com/@SamCorcos/meteor-react-ionic-mobile-app-part-1-the-basic-template-9355ebf3397f#.qtl4fl5st

when i add the line

```
ReactRouter=require("react-router");
```

inside app.browserify.js and run the application, i get the following error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/invariant'
```

I am using following versions

```
react                 0.14.3
cosmos:browserify     0.9.3
meteorhacks:npm       1.5.0
npm-container         1.2.0+
```

I am surely missing something thing here. Can anyone help.

Thanks,

Sri TejN

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. Just install the ReactRouter that is present in the meteor packages and do not include the line “ReactRouter = require(“react-router”);” in the file “ app.browserify.js”. But you can use the variable ReactRouter anywhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, in my case the solution also worked and added ReactRouter package:

```
meteor add reactrouter:react-router
```

Then commenting out line:

```
//ReactRouter = require("react-router");
```

In file lib/app.browserify.js and running Meteor again fixed the problem.

Thanks [Sri Tej Narala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2865639/sri-tej-narala).